# Why Parquet over some RDBMS like Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, parquet

I'm working to build a data architecture for my company. A simple ETL with internal and external data with the aim to build static dashboard and other to search trend.

I try to think about every step of the ETL process one by one and now I'm questioning about the **Load** part.

I plan to use Spark (LocalExcecutor on dev and a service on Azure for production) so I started to think about using Parquet into a Blob service. I know all the advantage of Parquet over CSV or other storage format and I really love this piece of technology. Most of the articles I read about Spark finish with a `df.write.parquet(...)`.

But I cannot figure it out why can I just start a Postgres and save everything here. I understand that we are not producing 100Go per day of data but I want to build something future proof in a fast growing company that gonna produce exponentially data by the business and by the logs and metrics we start recording more and more.

Any pros/cons by more experienced dev ?

EDIT : What also make me questioning this is this tweet : https://twitter.com/markmadsen/status/1044360179213651968

Comment: Dont know PostGRE SQL enough to throw my weight around, but I can for Parquet. Pro - saves space, is more efficient for highly parallelized output. Con - Cannot handle different data types being loaded to a column.

Comment: @afeldman: the DBMS is called PostgreSQL or simply Postgres

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main trade-off is one of cost and transactional semantics.

Using a DBMS means you can load data transactionally.  You also pay for both [storage and compute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/postgresql/server/) on an on-going basis.  The storage costs for the same amount of data are going to be more expensive in a managed DBMS vs a [blob store](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/).

It is also harder to scale out processing on a DBMS (it appears the largest size Postgres server Azure offers has 64 vcpus).  By storing data into an RDBMs you are likely going to run-up against IO or compute bottlenecks more quickly then you would with Spark + blob storage.  However, for many datasets this might not be an issue and as the tweet points out if you can accomplish everything inside a the DB with SQL then it is a much simpler architecture.

If you store Parquet files on a blob-store, updating existing data is difficult without regenerating a large segment of your data (and I don't know the details of Azure but generally can't be done transactionally).  The compute costs are separate from the storage costs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think I will go for RDBM with the volumetric that we have for now, then prepare the architecture with Parquet+Blob later. I will write this down in the documentation now.

Answer (score 6):

One of the issues I have with a dedicated Postgres server is that it's a fixed resource that's on 24/7.  If it's idle for 22 hours per day and under heavy load 2 hours per day (in particular if the hours aren't
continuous and are unpredictable)
then the server sizing during those 2 hours is going to be too low whereas during the other 22 hours it's too high.

If you store your data as parquet on Azure Data Lake Gen 2 and then use Serverless Synapse for SQL queries then you don't pay for anything on a 24/7 basis. When under heavy load, everything scales automatically.

The other benefit is that parquet files are compressed whereas Postgres doesn't store data compressed.

The downfall is "latency" (probably not the right term but it's how I think of it).  If you want to query a small amount of data then, in my experience, it's slower with the file + Serverless approach compared to a well indexed clustered or partitioned Postgres table.  Additionally, it's really hard to forecast your bill with the Serverless model coming from the server model.  There's definitely going to be usage patterns where Serverless is going to be more expensive than a dedicated server.  In particular if you do a lot of queries that have to read all or most of the data.

It's easier/faster to save a parquet than to do a lot of inserts. This is a double edged sword because the db guarantees acidity whereas saving parquet files doesn't.

Parquet storage optimization is its own task.  Postgres has autovacuum.  If the data you're consuming is published daily but you want it on a node/attribute/feature partition scheme then you need to do that manually (perhaps with spark pools).

Answer (score 4):

Storing data in Hadoop using raw file formats is terribly inefficient. Parquet is a Row Columnar file format well suited for querying large amounts of data in quick time. As you said above, writing data to Parquet from Spark is pretty easy. Also writing data using a distributed processing engine (Spark) to a distributed file system (Parquet+HDFS) makes the entire flow seamless. This architecture is well suited for OLAP type data.

Postgres on the other hand is a relational database. While it is good for storing and analyzing transactional data, it cannot be scaled horizontally as easily as HDFS can be. Hence when writing/querying large amount of data from Spark to/on Postgres, the database can become a bottleneck. But if the data you are processing is OLTP type, then you can consider this architecture.

Hope this helps

Comment: The question is more what is the more suitable for "small" Big Data in term of performance AND cost. Setting up an Hadoop cluster is oversized for us now but we tend too in a year maybe. I don't want to redo all the stack from scratch in a year, but changing the storage is manageable. Now we need ETL process, we need batch process to analyse data in an efficient way. From my reading, storing as Parquet is the must (not necessarily on Hadoop, Blob storage is sufficient here) but we, I think, not need it for now. I'm not sure.