# Polars + Parquet vs. Polars + mySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, parquet, python-polars

*[Note - I tried asking this on Stack Exchange/Software Engineering and Stack Exchange/Software Recommendations, and even Stack Exchange/Super User, but they didn't have tags for Polars or Parquet.]*

Let's say I've got data with 1 billion rows. Which of the following would be recommended:

- Store it in mySQL and query it via mySQL
- Store it in mySQL and query it via Polars
- Store it in Parquet and query it via Polars

Please let me know if I can provide any additional relevant info.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994758/why-parquet-over-some-rdbms-like-postgres/

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and say it: "it depends"

Storing it in a Parquet file makes a lot of sense; it's simple to track and fast to read / move + it's portable.

However, if you are reading only small parts of it, or modifying it regularly, or you want to have indexing logic, or you want to query it via SQL - then something like mySQL or DuckDB makes sense.